# How can I pass Rundeck variables to a JSON file?

Tags: json, rundeck

I have a JSON with key pairs and I want to access the values from Rundeck Options dynamically during the job execution.
For shell script, we can do a $RD_OPTIONS_<>.
Similarly is there some format I can use in a JSON file?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `@option.myoption@` in a [inline-scrip](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/node-steps/builtin.html#script-step)t step.

You need a tool to use on an inline script step to manipulate JSON files on Rundeck. I made an example using [JQ](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/). Alternatively, you can use bash script-fu to reach the same goal.

For example, using this JSON file:

```json
{
  "books": [{
      "fear_of_the_dark": {
          "author": "John Doe",
          "genre": "Mistery"
      }
  }]
}
```

Update the file with the following jq call:

#### To test directly in your terminal

```sh
jq '.books[].fear_of_the_dark += { "ISBN" : "9999" }' myjson.json
```

#### On Rundeck Inline-script

```sh
echo "$(jq ''.books[].fear_of_the_dark += { "ISBN" : "@option.isbn@" }'' myjson.json)" > myjson.json
```

Check how looks on an inline-script job (check [here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/creating-jobs.html#importing-job-definitions) to know how to import the job definition to your Rundeck instance).

```yaml
- defaultTab: nodes
  description: ''
  executionEnabled: true
  id: d8f1c0e7-a7c6-43d4-91d9-25331cc06560
  loglevel: INFO
  name: JQTest
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  options:
  - label: isbn number
    name: isbn
    required: true
  plugins:
    ExecutionLifecycle: null
  scheduleEnabled: true
  sequence:
    commands:
    - description: original file content
      exec: cat myjson.json
    - description: pass the option and save the content to the json file
      fileExtension: .sh
      interpreterArgsQuoted: false
      script: 'echo "$(jq ''.books[].fear_of_the_dark += { "ISBN" : "@option.isbn@"
        }'' myjson.json)" > myjson.json'
      scriptInterpreter: /bin/bash
    - description: modified file content (after jq)
      exec: cat myjson.json
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: node-first
  uuid: d8f1c0e7-a7c6-43d4-91d9-25331cc06560
```

Finally, check the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8BUK.jpg).

[Here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/node-steps/builtin.html#script-step) you can check more about executing scripts on Rundeck and [here](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) more about the JQ tool.

Comment: For testing i have used the same example you have given above but I am getting syntactical errs
```jq: error: Could not open file +=: No such file or directory
jq: error: Could not open file {: No such file or directory
jq: error: Could not open file ISBN: No such file or directory
jq: error: Could not open file :: No such file or directory
jq: error: Could not open file dancingcoder142: No such file or directory
jq: error: Could not open file }: No such file or directory```

Comment: Also, is there a way to access it directly in json instead of passing via script? That would be extremely helpful

Comment: Jq tool is designed for that reason. If you need to add, modify or delete elements from your json file, you need to manipulate the file using jq, bash or python scritps / routines. I updated my answer with an example to test directly in the linux terminal. Regards!